# How can I shift select multiple items in TKinter listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, selection

I am trying to select multiple items from a `Listbox`, it seems intuitive to press shift while selecting and have a block of items be selected, but there seems to be no build in functionality for this in Tkinter.

So I'm trying to implement it on my own, by registering the shift key and getting the latest selection. But I get stuck trying to figure out the latest selection in the `Listbox`. `listbox.get(ACTIVE)` seems to be one behind what I expect.

Here is what I have tried to do so far, I am aware that I need to do more when I know the newest selection but that will come later.

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI():
    def __init__(self,frame): # Some Init
        self.listbox = Listbox(root, height=20, width=51, selectmode=MULTIPLE, exportselection=0, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)
        # -- Some Grid setup here --
        self.listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.selectionCallback)
        frame.bind("<Shift_L>", self.shiftCallback)
        frame.bind("<KeyRelease-Shift_L>", self.shiftCallback)

    def selectionCallback(self,event):
        print self.listbox.get(ACTIVE) # This is where im stuck

    def shiftCallback(self,event):
        if event.type is 2: #KeyPress
            self.shift = True
        elif event.type is 3: #KeyRelease
            self.shift = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    GUI(root)
```

Comment: I think `selectmode=EXTENDED` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior you seem to want actually *is* available by default, use

```
Listbox(..., selectmode=EXTENDED, ...)
```

From [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201117030020/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#patterns):

> The listbox offers four different selection modes through the **selectmode** option. These are **SINGLE** (just a single choice), **BROWSE** (same, but the selection can be moved using the mouse), **MULTIPLE** (multiple item can be choosen, by clicking at them one at a time), or **EXTENDED** (multiple ranges of items can be chosen, using the Shift and Control keyboard modifiers). The default is **BROWSE**. Use **MULTIPLE** to get “checklist” behavior, and **EXTENDED** when the user would usually pick only one item, but sometimes would like to select one or more ranges of items.

---

As for `listbox.get(ACTIVE)`, the item that is `ACTIVE` is the one that is underlined. You can see that this is only updated upon release of the mouse button. Because the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event is triggered on the mouse press, you get the previously selected item, because the `ACTIVE` is not updated yet.